# Error in saving and serving a model in tensorflow-serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

How should I save my trained model using tf.saved_model.simple_save so that I can make requests using tensorflow-serving

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
values = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w), b)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y, logits=layer))
optimize = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(layer, 1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  for _ in range(10000):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x:batch[0],y:batch[1]})

  !rm -rf "/model"
  export_dir = "/model/1"

  #Problem here
  tf.saved_model.simple_save(
      sess,
      export_dir=export_dir,
      inputs={"x":x},
      outputs={"accuracy":accuracy}
  )
```

When I run:

```
!saved_model_cli show --dir {export_dir} --all

I get:
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['x'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 784)
        name: Placeholder:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['accuracy'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: ()
        name: Mean_1:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

My output is of shape() instead of (-1,x) or that kind of format.
When I send a request, I get no response. Since accuracy is an operation I get no response. How can I change it to a variable or how can I use {t.name for t in model.outputs} which is used in keras?

Answer (score 0):

The output in simple_save seems not correct. It should be layer, but not accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the last line of the code, `outputs={"accuracy":accuracy}`. The issue will be resolved if `accuracy` is replaced with 'layer'. So, the code can be as shown below:

```
tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, export_dir=export_dir, inputs={"x":x},
outputs={"Predicted_Output":layer})
```